# type "e" does not exist , Redshift through Postgresql connector in php codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, amazon-redshift, php-7

i'm using Redshift through Postgresql connector i got the following error while querying in php codeigniter 3.x, php version 7.0
the model is as follows

```
$subQuery = "select max(button_history_id) as button_history_id  from button_history
        where site_id =".$site_id." group by button_history_id ";

        $this->another->select('cms_group_id');
        $this->another->from('button_history');
        $this->another->where('button_history_id IN ('.$subQuery.")");
        $this->another->where('cms_group_id !=', '');
        $queryGrp = $this->another->get();
        $grpIds = array();
        foreach($queryGrp->result_array() as $grps){
            if($grps['cms_group_id'])
            $grpIds = array_merge($grpIds,explode(',', $grps['cms_group_id']));
        }
        if($grpIds){
            $grpIds = array_unique($grpIds);
            $this->another->select('content_history_id, (content_id),content_name,content_type');
            $this->another->from('content_history');
            $this->another->where_in('content_id',$grpIds);
            $this->another->group_by('content_history_id,content_id,content_name,content_type');
            $this->another->order_by('content_id ,content_history_id',"desc");
            $queryG = $this->another->get();
            $result1 = $queryG->result_array();
        }
```

but an unwanted E' is appending before the values as follows

ERROR: type "e" does not exist

```
SELECT "content_history_id", (content_id), "content_name", "content_type" FROM "content_history" WHERE "content_id" IN( E'358', E'357', E'359', E'361', E'408', E'398', E'362', E'366', E'363') GROUP BY "content_history_id", "content_id", "content_name", "content_type" ORDER BY "content_id" DESC, "content_history_id" DESC
```

this E'358' "E" is causing all the trouble , could anyone has any suggestions please respond. i'm new to this, and hv no idea what is the reson, i have added th info below.

php version :7.0
codeigniter :3.x
OS: Centos 6.9

[image]

Comment: share code where you create `$grpIds` ?

Comment: I've updated the code, which includes $grpIds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This E is for escaping character in PostgreSQL. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

Try to adding a third parameter to `where_in`, which avoid escaping.

```
$this->another->where_in('content_id',$grpIds, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this exact error while connecting to AWS Redshift using SQL Workbench.

You might get this error when you are using Postgres JDBC driver(org.postgresql.Driver) to connect to Redshift. Instead, you should use Redshift JDBC driver(com.amazon.redshift.Driver). See - [this](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/dbms-problems.html#pg-problems)

[image]

Issue got fixed when I used the Redshift driver.