# PostgreSQL column casting in Codeigniter for datatables

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm currently working on a Codeigniter 3 project that has real time search values using datatables, the project was on MySQL and all worked fine and it has to be migrated to PostgreSQL and now the search doesn't work because is needed to add explicit type casts in the ID column, this is the error: **ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ text.**

I figured how to do it by adding **::varchar** after de column name and I tested it typing the Query directly on PHPpgadmin and it works, but I can't find how i exactly i can do this in the CI code

This is the code

```
$datatable->db_search(array(
        "consultas.nombre",
        "usuarios.username",
        "u2.username",
        "consultas.guest_email",
        "consultas.last_reply_string",
        "consultas.ID",
    )
);
```

db_search function

```
public function db_search($columns) 
{
    if(!empty($this->search)) {
        if($this->search_type == 0) {

            // Search all columns for likeness
            $words = explode(" ", $this->search);
            $this->CI->db->group_start();
            foreach($words as $word) {
                foreach($columns as $field) {
                    $this->CI->db->or_like($field, $word);
                }
            }
            $this->CI->db->group_end();

        } elseif($this->search_type == 1) {

            // Search all colums for likeness for whole string
            $this->CI->db->group_start();
            foreach($columns as $field) {
                 $this->CI->db->or_like($field, $this->search);
            }
            $this->CI->db->group_end();

        } else {

            // Search for each individual column. 
            // First 2 indexes are reserved for above
            if(isset($columns[$this->search_type-2])) {
                $this->CI->db->group_start();
                $this->CI->db->or_like($columns[$this->search_type-2],  $this->search);
                $this->CI->db->group_end();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Already tried:

`"consultas.ID::varchar"`,

`"'consultas.ID', '1011%'"`

Comment: Please, post the code of `$datatable->db_search()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid the escaping in those columns you are casting.

Normally the last parameter for QueryBuilder methods is for escaping, which can be true or false (default: true, DO escape)

```
$this->CI->db->or_like($field, $word, false); // <-- false, do not escape
```

See my answer here to a similar question: 
[type "e" does not exist , Redshift through Postgresql connector in php codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059812/type-e-does-not-exist-redshift-through-postgresql-connector-in-php-codeignit/52061843#52061843)

---

Try to cast this way

`CAST(consultas.ID as TEXT);`

Comment: i tried like that and the error remains, i actually want to be able do to search by ID too, thanks

Comment: @AlfredoSanroman Right after before return the results put `echo $this->db->last_query();` and post here the complete query.

Comment: Why do you need to search like on integer column?

Comment: Hi, now i getting a different error:
https://pastebin.com/N8pDgE3U, for some reason is calling the column as consulta.id not consulta.ID

Comment: Maybe is better to use quotes `CAST("consultas"."ID" as TEXT)` (I'm not sure, I don't have a PG here to test)

Comment: Code is not accepting the quotes, syntax error    "CAST("consultas"."ID" as TEXT)" :(

Comment: 'CAST("......"."..." as TEXT)': note the single quotes, it's PHP. Or add slashes on inner quotes

Comment: lol forgot about that the level of fustration was high but, guees what? that worked like a charm, you are the man, marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

Make 3rd parameter of or_like FALSE for consultas.ID.

```
if($field == 'consultas.ID')
{
$this->CI->db->or_like($field, $word, FALSE);
}
else{
$this->CI->db->or_like($field, $word);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, the problem remains i set it like this:
// Search all columns for likeness
    $words = explode(" ", $this->search);
    $this->CI->db->group_start();
    foreach($words as $word) {
     foreach($columns as $field) {
                if($field == 'consultas.ID')
                {
                $this->CI->db->or_like($field, $word, FALSE);
                }
                else{
                $this->CI->db->or_like($field, $word);
                }
    }
    $this->CI->db->group_end();
                }